# How do I point to a properties file expected by a native java library jar in Play2/Scala?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm trying to tie in an API for the St. Louis Federal Reserve data (FRED) into a Play2 web app. You can see the API here: http://api.stlouisfed.org/docs/fred/ under java.

I put the FREDAPI.jar into the scala/play classpath and I'm able to import com.uniservsolutions.stlouisfed.fred without a problem.

But the API needs the API key to instantiate a 'session' and that is put into a file .properties (I have fred.properties). API docs instruct me to declare the following at the commandline:

```
java -Dcom.uniservsolutions.stlouisfed.fred.properties="fred"
```

This will read the contents of fred.properties:

```
fredAPIKey=<my key>
fredURL=http://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/
sendGetRetryCount=5
sendGetTimeoutMilliseconds=10000
sendRequestRetryCount=5
```

But I'm not familiar how to do this in Play. I have found info on JAVA_OPTS but I'm unsure where to declare or if indeed that will work. Finally, when I deploy this (currently staging on Heroku) where will I declare this (heroku's Procfile?).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered quite by accident that you can declare java command line args for play e.g.:

```
play -Dcom.uniservsolutions.stlouisfed.fred.properties="var"
```